# Acessing current form on create Magnolia CMS

Tags: java, content-management-system, nodes, jcr, magnolia

I'm creating an Magnolia app with some custom fields. At this point I'm quite stuck.
**OBJECTIVE:** Creating multiples checkbox fields where only one can be true.
**CURRENT ENVIRONMENT:** I have a multifield with a composite field inside. That said composite have 4 textfields and a custom checkbox field (this is the one that can only have one checked)
[CurrentEnvironment Image](https://i.stack.imgur.com/D38MD.png)
**PROBLEM:** I can't acess the current form to uncheck the others checkbox fields without saving previously
**WHAT I'VE TRIED:** At this moment I'm trying with `DetailLocation` to acess the `Session` on that said location but no good, because it can't acess the session on this point.
Thanks for any information or guidance.

Answer (score 1):

Each field is atomic and doesn't have access to the higher ups. You either need to create custom field that will have those individual checkboxes in it, or you need to write custom FieldPresenter for the composite that will pass over some listener or other object that could hold or change the state of other fields.

Or you simply forget about checkboxes and use radio button group to achieve the same.

Comment: Hi @Jan, thanks for the advice. How would you do it using radio buttons? I need to have a dynamic multivalue field to let the user add how many rows he wants... Using radio buttons wouldn't instatiate a new field everytime a row has been added?(this wouldn't bring the same problems stated above?)

Comment: Yes, it would didn’t realize your user needs to add different amount of values every time. So you are back to original solution. Tho it might still be easier to develop custom radio button where editor provides list of values to create items from then binding together multiple checkboxes to allow only single one to be selected.